# Ignore chained calls in assert_has_calls with pytest mocker

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, pytest

When using `mocker` from [`pytest-mock`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/), how can I use `has_calls` to check the calls to a specific method without checking all the calls made to the return value of that method?

For example:

```
import subprocess
from unittest import mock

def test_foo(mocker):
    m = mocker.patch('test_main.subprocess')
    r1 = subprocess.run(['foo'])
    r1.check_returncode()
    r2 = subprocess.run(['bar'])
    r2.check_returncode()

    m.run.assert_has_calls([
        mock.call(['foo']),
        mock.call(['bar']),
    ])
```

Fails with:

```
E       AssertionError: Calls not found.
E       Expected: [call(['foo']), call(['bar'])]
E       Actual: [call(['foo']),
E        call().check_returncode(),
E        call(['bar']),
E        call().check_returncode()]
```

Why are calls to the return value also included? I just want to check that I had a call to `subprocess.run(['foo'])` **followed by** a call to `subprocess.run(['bar'])`. I don't care about calls made to anything it returns, but I *do* care about the order of calls to `run` itself.

Answer (score 3):

Add `any_order=True` to your `assert_has_calls` call, like this:

```
m.run.assert_has_calls([
    mock.call(['foo']),
    mock.call(['bar']),
], any_order=True)
```

The reason is, it looks like `assert_has_calls` uses the `mock_calls` attribute on a mock which based on the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.mock_calls):

> records all calls to the mock object, its methods, magic methods and return value mocks.

With `assert_has_calls` though, it's not an exact matching problem it was just the ordering that was failing.

EDIT: Since order matters, use `call_args_list`. Like this:

```
def test_foo(mocker):
    m = mocker.patch('subprocess_test.subprocess')
    r1 = subprocess.run(['foo'])
    r1.check_returncode()
    r2 = subprocess.run(['bar'])
    r2.check_returncode()

    assert [mock.call(['foo']), mock.call(['bar'])] == m.run.call_args_list
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at `mock_calls`, that explains the behavior. However, `any_order` will not work for me: > I just want to check that I had a call to subprocess.run(['foo']) **followed by** a call to subprocess.run(['bar'])

Comment: Just wanted to point out here that call_args_list is the real answer here, and should be accepted (but also probably that the answer itself should be edited to put that part of the answer prominently).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`assert_any_call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_any_call):

```
m.run.assert_any_call(['foo'])
m.run.assert_any_call(['bar'])
```

Comment: `assert_any_call` does not allow me to check the order. > > I just want to check that I had a call to subprocess.run(['foo']) **followed by** a call to subprocess.run(['bar']). Both answers seem to miss this, so I'll edit the question to make it more clear.